# Number of photoelectrons vs Frequency

Tags: atoms, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

This is the graph plotted between photocurrent (proportional to number of photoelectrons) and potential applied with different frequencies.
[image]
<sub>(source: [indicareer.com](http://www.indicareer.com/entrance-exams/mht-cet/physics/Electrons-and-Photons-1_files/image005.gif))</sub>

As it can be seen, the number of photoelectrons released becomes same for all frequencies finally.

But if you see the region between 0 V and the point where all the curves meet, the number of photoelectrons are slightly different.

Does that mean that under certain conditions photocurrent will depend on frequency too?

Ofcourse, more energy => more speed of electrons, faster electrons reach the other end far quicker than slower electrons, thus lesser time taken and hence more current.

Why does this not happen at higher potentials , then?

Comment: What is your source for the diagram?

Comment: @BillN http://www.indicareer.com/entrance-exams/mht-cet/physics/Electrons-and-Photons-1_files/image005.gif

Comment: The photoelectric current depends on the intensity of the light. I would take that diagram as an oversimplified schematic rather than a real physical measurement. For the same power of the light, the photons flux decreases with increasing energy.

Comment: @CuriousOne But then why is every graph shown like this?

Comment: Why are people writing bad textbooks? Because they don't know better or they don't care or they think that lying to the kids is easier than explaining the facts precisely? That's not a physics question, though, is it?

Comment: We need to know some context. What type of device is this a characteristic curve for? What does "collector potential" mean for the device? Is the intensity of the light constant? There's not enough information about the diagram to give any reasonable answer.  It looks to me like a photomultiplier saturation diagram.

Comment: @CuriousOne I agree  with you on that. Could you provide me with a graph drawn using experimental data? That'd be helpful.

Comment: I am not even sure such a graph would be helpful since it would distract from the actually important physics. For the case of the photoelectric effect one does, thankfully, not have to care about the absolute intensity/power. Experiments in which one does are hellish.

Comment: @CuriousOne I get you. Thanks though.